# nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, annotations

I am getting the following validation error when I try to submit my form. The dropdown box populated with values from Document.java gives this error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type 
testapp.domain.Document for property document_number; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] 
to required type [testapp.domain.Document] for property document_number: no matching 
editors or conversion strategy found
```

Is there something wrong with my mapping?

Document.java mapping

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="document_number", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<DocumentRevision> documentRevisions;

public void setDocumentRevisions(Set<DocumentRevision> documentRevisions){
    this.documentRevisions = documentRevisions;
}
```

DocumentRevision.java mapping

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="DOCUMENT_NUMBER")
private Document document_number; 

public void setDocument_number(Document document_number){
    this.document_number = document_number;
}

public Document getDocument_number(){
    return document_number;
}
```

The relationship between the two tables is that several *DocumentRevisions* can have the same *DocumentNumber* but a single *DocumentRevision* can only have one *DocumentNumber*

Thank you for your help

/D

**Edit**

I am using spring 3.0 and hibernate 3. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499641/how-to-populate-dropdown-box-in-spring-mvc) is a recent thread by me which includes the controller and jsp page.

**Edit 2**

Here is the DAO Implementation method that is supposed to save the document_number into DocumentRevision

```
    public void saveDocumentRevision(DocumentRevision documentRevision) {
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(documentRevision); 
}
```

**Edit 3**

I believe this is the part of the code where document_number should be recorded. Do I have to use "documentNumberList" somewhere in the .POST method? How would I do that in that case?

part of controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getDocumentRevision(Model model) {
DocumentRevision documentRevision = new DocumentRevision();
model.addAttribute("documentRevisionAttribute", documentRevision);
model.addAttribute("documentNumberList", documentService.retrieveAllDocumentNumbers());

return "new-documnent-revision";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postDocumentRevision(@ModelAttribute("documentRevisionAttribute") @Valid DocumentRevision documentRevision, BindingResult result) {

if(result.hasErrors()){
    return "new-document-revision";
}

documentRevisionService.createDocumentRevision(documentRevision);
return "redirect:/testapp/document-revision/list";  
}
```

**Update**

I have added the following to my controller:

```
    /**
 * Property editor to map Documents from documents IDs.
 */

 class DocumentPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Document value =  documentService.retrieveDocumentNumber(text);
        setValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        Document d = (Document) getValue();
        return d != null ? String.valueOf(d.getDocumentNumber()) : "";
    }

}


@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Document.class, new DocumentPropertyEditor());
}
```

I am now getting a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
testapp.controller.DocumentRevisionController$DocumentPropertyEditor.getAsText(DocumentRevisionController.java:59)
```

Why isn't the getter in th PropertyEditor getting a value?

**Edit 4**

the retrieveDocumentNumber(text) method:

```
    public Document retrieveDocumentNumber(String text){
    return (Document) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Document.class, text);
}
```

Comment: What kind of dropdown box are you talking about? What's the framework you're working with?

Comment: @rolve sorry for not supplying that information. Please see my edit

Comment: I think the problem is not in the ORM mapping. According to the error message, something tries to put a String into `Document.document_number`. Where is the code that does this?

Comment: @rolve I added the DAO method that is supposed to save the new documentRevision with the document_number chosen from the dropbox

Comment: When the DAO method is called, the `DocumentRevision` object is already updated, right? I think the error happens before that, when the framework tries to set the `document_number` field.

Comment: @rolve yes I believe you are correct. I added the controller code that should handle the setting of the document_number field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring WebDataBinder fail to convert the `String document_number` to a Document  instance when 
populating  the documentRevision model attribute.  You have two posibilities:

- Initialize the `WebDataBinder` with a `PropertyEditor` that can handle the conversion. Most direct, but work only for this controller.
- Register a `Converter<String, Document>`

if choose the first, annotate a controller method with `@InitBinder` annotation and register 
the property editor. Seems like you only need to fetch the document from database by document_number. See [Customizing WebDataBinder initatization](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder) on reference documentation.

**Edit**

Property editor example to map Documents to/from Ids Strings.

```
/**
 * Property editor to map Documents from documents IDs.
 */
 class DocumentPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Long id = Long.parseLong(text);
        Document value = id == 0 ? null : documentService.get(id);
        setValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        Document d = (Document) getValue();
        return d != null ? String.valueOf(d.getId()) : "";
    }
}
```

For the second approach, look at [Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) to see 
how to create and register a `Converter` in the Spring `ConversionService`.

Comment: Is this the right way to write the controller method?
` @InitBinder
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.registerCustomEditor(Document.class, new DocumentEditor())
 }` 
How would I write the DocumentEditor?

Comment: I add an example to the answer that use a documentService to fetch Documents

Comment: I am getting this error now when I enter the add page:" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "DOC 9991783478"" Do you know how I can resolve this?

Comment: You need to convert the document_number String to a Document in the setAsText() method. I supose that you use Longs as Document PK in the sample code (that is only a sample, not for verbatin copy)). If you are using String Keys for document_number, dont convert it to longs (Long.parseLong(...)).

Comment: Would you mind showing me how? I'm afraid that I don't fully understand how the property editor works. Should I initialize "String id;" but then what value do I give id? Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it

Comment: The value of text in setAsText(String text) come from post data, ie the document_number that user picked on the comboBox. Convert it to a Document and call to setValue with it.  PropertyEditors are part of JavaBeans specification.

Comment: I believe I have done this but the getAsText is giving me a NullPointerException. I have added the new code to my original question. Can you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: I will accept your answer since your solution is working for saving to the database. Thanks! The conversion is however not working when I want to display the table. I will start a new thread about that issue