# Spring MVC 3. form selection options

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC and I'm trying to get the values to jsp form selection list from controller. 
Selection list is displayed, but it empty. I tried different examples etc, but didn't still couldn't find, where's the issue.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
       @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView login() {
          return new ModelAndView("login", "command", new Person());
       }


       @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public String login(@ModelAttribute("xxx")Person person, ModelMap model) {
           Map<String,String> list = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
           list.put("opt1", "value1");
           list.put("opt2", "value2");
           model.put("list", list);

          return "newView";
       }
}
```

newView.jsp:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/xxx/saveUser" command="">
   <table>
    <tr>
      <form:select path="name">
        <form:options items="${list}" />
      </form:select>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

Person.java model:

```
public class Person {
       private String name;
//Getters and setters and more values etc...
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question.

[How to populate dropdown box in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499641/how-to-populate-dropdown-box-in-spring-mvc)

This has answer for you.