# Spring MVC - Share Data

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring and I've been using Spring boot with Freemarker template to buld a simple blog application. In my application I have a navbar.ftl which is shared by all other views.
In this nav bar I want to access a list of all Authors in order to show their names in a drop down (code below), but I'm not sure how to access it here, since this navbar is shared between all views.

```
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Authors <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <#--Need to list all authors here. How???-->
      </ul>
    </li>
```

I have an AuthorRepository where I can find all authors, but I'm not sure how to use it in my view (I don't think the view could access the model directly anyway).

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {
}
```

Any idea how I could have a list of authors in this navbar so I can show their names?

Comment: There are many example on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499641/how-to-populate-dropdown-box-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218693/how-to-pass-data-from-formselect-spring-mvc

Comment: Thanks, but I know I can use model.addAttribute("authors", authorArray) in an specific controller. The problem is that this nav bar is shared between all my views, so I don't want to add this attribute for every single controller in my app.

In ruby for example, I would do something like this (accessing the model directly from my view). So what's the best way to do this using Spring?

            <% Author.all.order("LOWER (name)").each do |author| %>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "#{author.name}", author_path(author) %>
              </li>

Answer (score 0):

I think controller you can create function common ShareData. Put all data for method, when need you use this with call function ShareData(). That's all I thought.